# The maximum number of matches. In two lists

Tags: c#, sql-server, list, linq-to-sql

There is such a problem. There is one list that is taken from the database, there is a second which is formed during the program.
The table is as follows:

```
id name
One my foo1 foo2 foo3
2 my fow1 foo2 foo3
...
```

And so on.
list that is generated during the operation of the program takes the data from the file.
And is:

```
id name parent
...
```

The problem is where the column parent id number column of the table that is in the database.
At the moment, made ​​the decision:

```
int countMatch = 0;
foreach (var productse in prod)
{
    var splitted = productse.name.Replace("  ", " ").Split(' ');
    int maxmatch = splitted.Count(s => addProd.name.Contains(s));

    if (maxmatch > countMatch) countMatch = maxmatch;
}

var fixedCount = addProd.name.Split(' ').Count()/1.5;// 1.5 Choose the most best rate
if (countMatch <= fixedCount && prod.All(x => !x.name.ToUpper().Contains(addProd.name.ToUpper())))
  prod.Add(addProd);
```

after that "prod" list is loaded into the database

This solution works, but not very well. Some records are not created because of some names best fit smaller.

Sample data that I'm trying to load:

```
Intel Core i3-2120 3.3GHz 3Mb 2xDDR3-1333 HDGraphics2000 TDP-65w LGA1155 OEM - name created
```

The following data are obtained id parent (Entry above) :

```
Intel Core i3-2120 3.3GHz 3Mb 2xDDR3-1333 HDGraphics2000 TDP-65w LGA1155 OEM
Intel Core i3-2120 3.3GHz 3Mb 2xDDR3-1333 HDGraphics2000 TDP-65w LGA1155 BOX w/cooler
Intel Core i3-2130 3.4GHz 3Mb 2xDDR3-1333 HDGraphics2000 TDP-65w LGA1155 OEM
Intel Core i3-3210 3.2GHz 3Mb 2xDDR3-1333 HDGraphics2500 TDP-55w LGA1155 OEM
Intel Core i3-3225 3.3GHz 3Mb 2xDDR3-1333 HDGraphics4000 TDP-55w LGA1155 OEM
Intel Core i3-3225 3.3GHz 3Mb 2xDDR3-1333 HDGraphics4000 TDP-55w LGA1155 BOX w/cooler
Intel Core i3-3240 3.4GHz 3Mb 2xDDR3-1333 HDGraphics2500 TDP-55w LGA1155 OEM
Intel Core i3-3240 3.4GHz 3Mb 2xDDR3-1333 HDGraphics2500 TDP-55w LGA1155 BOX w/cooler
Intel Core i5-2500K 3.3GHz (TB up to 3.7GHz) 6Mb 2xDDR3-1333 HDGraphics3000 TDP-95w LGA1155 OEM
Intel Core i5-3550 3.3GHz (TB up to 3.7GHz) 6Mb 2xDDR3-1333 HDGraphics2500 TDP-77w LGA1155 OEM
Intel Core i5-3550 3.3GHz (TB up to 3.7GHz) 6Mb 2xDDR3-1333 HDGraphics2500 TDP-77w LGA1155 BOX w/cooler
```

Need to put the data in a table, and if the data is similar to the maximum number of matches you get to the parent. Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

Can you write more clearly what you should do? As I understand you want to link row from text file to the row in data base by identifying most common symbols, where the begining of text is the same. Correct me if it is wrong.

At first try to use **regular expressions**, wich are kings in text processing. 
You could iterate and remove last word with space in line text one by one.

```
foreach (var fProduct in fileProducts)
{
    // remove blank spaces >= 2
    var fProductCleared = Regex.Replace(fProduct, @"\s{2,}", "");

    // search best match in data base
    bool isMatched = FunctionToMatchInDB(fProductClear); // search the whole text
    if(!isMatched)
    {
        // remove word by word from the end
        while(fProductClear.Contains(' '))
        {
             // remove last word with space from the end of line
             fProductClear = Regex.Replace(fProductClear,@"\s*[^\s]+\s*$", "");
             bool isMatched = FunctionToMatchInDB(fProductClear); 
             if(!isMatched)
                 break; // TODO: 
        }
    }

}
```